# Access class name in a window element

Tags: javascript, html

```
var win = window.open('', '_blank', 'PopUp' + ',width=1300,height=800');
win.document.write(`
<div class="col-sm-24">
    <p class="page-title headerLabel"></p>
</div>`);
```

I have a window element with the class headerLabel. In this paragraph tag I want to inject some data which is liable to change... I have tried

```
var heading = Some Heading;
win.document.write($('.headerLabel').html(heading));
```

but it's not working

Comment: What is `win` in that code?

Comment: Added the edit in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `win` is a different window from the one containing this code, you need to tell jQuery to use the other document instead of its default one (the current window). You also don't want `write`, as you're *modifying* an existing element.

```
$(win.document).find(".headerLabel").html("The new content");
```

should do it, although if you're going to do anything complex with jQuery in another window, it's usually better to load jQuery in the other window and then call that copy.

You could also easily do this without jQuery, which removes that concern:

```
win.document.querySelector(".headerLabel").innerHTML = "The new content";
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is this line:** `win.document.write($('.headerLabel').html(heading));`

```
// I don't know what is win. So, let's make an example thinking this is another window.
var win = window;
```

You're trying to write the result of `$('.headerLabel').html(heading)`.  So, just call the `.html` function.

```js
var win = window; // I don't know what is win. So, let's make an example thinking this is another window.

win.document.write(`
<div class="col-sm-24">
    <p class="page-title headerLabel"></p>
</div>`);

var heading = "Some Heading";
$('.headerLabel', win.document).html(heading)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mishka the `win` variable is another window?  If so, this should work.